# Getting Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'. on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to check if the email and password in the login are in an array which I get through a function `getUsers()`, but when I try to check it with `find()` it says `Property "find' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>*`. I don't know how to resolve it, I read that with pipe, but I don't really understand how it works.

On user.service.ts:

```
getUsers(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.usersUrl);
  }



 login(email:string, password:string):Observable<any>{
  const users=this.getUsers();
    
  return users.find(
    (user:any)=> user.email === email && user.password ===password);
  
      
  }
```

Comment: `this.getUsers()` returns an observable, so `const users` is an observable **not** an array, so `users.find` doesn't make sense. You probably wanted something like `return this.getUsers().pipe(map((users) => ...)))`. Angular uses RxJS heavily, I would strongly recommend reading up on it.

Comment: See e.g. https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Answer (score 3):

Alternativeley you could convert the http.get to a promise and turn your login method into an async method:

```
public async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<YourUserType> {
  const users = await this.getUsers().toPromise();
  return users.find(({ email: eml, password: pw }) => eml === email && pw === password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to subscribe to your observable if want to retrieve data inside of it.
in your case `getUsers()` is returning an observable of users and you can subscribe to it inside your `login()` function:

```
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const users = this.users;
    let loggedUser

    // subscribe to the users observable
    users.subscribe(usersList => {
      // find the user
      const userExists =  usersList.find(user => user.email === email && user.password === password)
      loggedUser = userExists
    });
    
    // return the found user as an observable, if nothing is found, the observable is gonna contain undefined
    return of(loggedUser)
  }
```

Here is a small demo to help you out: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bq29jo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will try tomorrow I already have a headache.

Comment: Note that absolutely *doesn't* work, you return `of(undefined)` because the subscribe callback won't be executed before the return is reached. Because it's asynchronous, which is why you're using observables to start with.